# Getting ListFields from Autocad DWG using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, fields-attributes, python-addin, dwg

I am trying to get LisfFields from AutoCad DWG, to arcpy Add-In, i have tried

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    Layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    for Layers in Layers:
        if Layers.name==Target_Layer:
            fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(Target_Layer)
            for field in fieldList:
                fieldName=str(field.name)
```

It works for Feature Class Layers but not for DWG.

Is there other way to do this?

I have also tried MakeFeatureLayer before LisfFields and it did not work.

Comment: I think you may have to convert your DWG to a Feature Class in order to access that information.  ArcMap has limited functionality with DWGs.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the help for [ListFields (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000012000000) that ArcPy function:

> Lists the fields in a **feature class, shapefile, or table** in a
>   specified dataset. The returned list can be limited with search
>   criteria for name and field type and will contain field objects.

Consequently, as commented by @Baltok, I think you will need to convert your CAD drawing to a feature class before using ListFields on it.

One tool that should be able to do this is [CAD to Geodatabase (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000001z000000) which:

> Reads a CAD dataset and creates feature classes of the drawing. The
>   feature classes are written to a geodatabase feature dataset.